# RegExp Validate SMS Text

Tags: regex, validation, sms

How do i write a RegExp to validate SMS Text is only keyboard character (abc, ABC, 123, ~!@#$%^&*()`[]{}|;':',./<>?)

Thanks...

Comment: Any luck with comments and answers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default GSM character set is defined in [GSM 03.38](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38). Assuming you're looking at decoded text, not the 7bit packed format that is really used, a regex like the following should limit you to the allowable characters

```
"@£$¥èéùìòÇ\fØø\nÅåΔ_ΦΓΛΩΠΨΣΘΞÆæßÉ !\"#¤%&'()*+,-./[0-9]:;<=>\?¡[A-Z]ÄÖÑÜ§¿[a-z]äöñüà\^\{\}\[~\]\|€"
```

Note though that it is possible to sent unicode UCS-2 messages, at which point the handset receiving the message has to have suitable glyphs for presentation to the user, the unicode itself is not a limiting factor.

Comment: Worked like a charm, although I had to add [ and ] at start and end and test it pr character.

Answer (score 4):

I propose to do it manually.

You just have to take care of some exceptions like the `[` `]` (need escaping) the backquote and the quote depending on the language you are writing with (since it coud end the string of the pattern)

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$%^&*()`\[\]{};':,./<>?| ]*$
```

Maybe it would require a little tuning. I'm pretty sure that - and _ are accepted in SMS texts.

Answer (score 1):

I searched a lot but, I think best one is.

```
function CharecterControl(input) {
    var str = /[^A-Za-z0-9 \\r\\n@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå\u0394_\u03A6\u0393\u0027\u0022\u039B\u03A9\u03A0\u03A8\u03A3\u0398\u039EÆæßÉ!\#$%&amp;()*+,\\./\-:;&lt;=&gt;?¡ÄÖÑÜ§¿äöñüà^{}\\\\\\[~\\]|\u20AC]*/; 
    return !new RegExp(str).test(input);       
}
```

Comment: it seems that backslashes have been escaped too many times in this regex. Wouldn't the right one be `[^A-Za-z0-9 \r\n@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå\u0394_\u03A6\u0393\u0027\u0022\u039B\u03A9\u03A0\u03A8\u03A3\u0398\u039EÆæßÉ!\#$%&amp;()*+,\./\-:;&lt;=&gt;?¡ÄÖÑÜ§¿äöñüà^{}\\\[~\]|\u20AC]`?

Comment: @zVictor is correct - that is the proper character string. Also, this sample threw me off - a better function name is `isGsmEncoded` - or for the reverse (if you want to test for non-GSM characters instead, just remove the `!`), it could then be called `hasUcs2Characters`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm a little late to the party, but I've been fighting with this. I recently ran across Twitter's Open Source Project:

https://github.com/twitter/cloudhopper-commons-charset

It provides a great way of cleaning Strings before sending them based on charsets. It also supports encoding a string as bytes based on a SMS friendly charset.  Here is my example cleaning an existing string before sending through SMS using their libraries:

```
public static String cleanSMS(String msg) {
    Charset charset = CharsetUtil.map(CharsetUtil.NAME_GSM7);
    StringBuilder cleaned  = new StringBuilder(msg);
    log.info("Accent chars replaced: " + MobileTextUtil.replaceAccentedChars(cleaned));
    log.info("Safe chars replaced: " + MobileTextUtil.replaceSafeUnicodeChars(cleaned));
    return CharsetUtil.normalize(cleaned.toString(), charset);
}
```